# React. Change the day of the week in the library react-bootstrap-daterangepicker

Tags: reactjs

There is a great library called react-bootstrap-daterangepicker, but it doesn't suit me that the day of the week starts with Su. Maybe someone came across. How do I make the day of the week start with Mo?

Comment: I figured it out, the answer is no longer needed. P.S.: I don’t know how to delete my question ...

Answer (score 0):

You should change locale for moment library.

For example - add in your App.js file

```
import 'moment/locale/en-gb'
```

P.S. Don't forget install moment library.